# AJAX dropdown list down not update with var string variable

Tags: ajax

I have a test script to update a county drop down list whenever the year or state is updated.  When I used a literal string when year is selected, the county list updated fine.  However when I tried to the county list using an ajax call and used a (var options) to build the list, the drop down list value changed to an empty list even though I verified the value of (var options) contains valid drop down list options.

Please help!
Thanks,

```
$('#State').on("change", function () {
            var state = $('#State').val();
            var year = $('#Year').val();
            var obj = {
                state: state,
                year:year
            };
            alert("State changed:" + state + ":" + year);


            AjaxCall('/RIC/GetCounties', JSON.stringify(obj), 'POST').done
             (function (response) {
                    if (response) {

                        $('#DataId').html("<option value='test'>Test</option>");
                        var options = '';
                        options += "<option value='Select'>Select</option>\n";
                        for (i in response) {
                            options += "<option value='" + response[i].DataId + "'>" + response[i].County + "</option>\n";
                        }
                        $('#DataId').html("<option value='Select'>Select-S</option><option value='16'>Alameda-S</option>");
                        alert("Statitical Areas(S): " + options);
                        //$('#DataId').html(options);     //This should work.  How to get the value of options into the string
                        //$('#DataId').append(options);
                    }
             }).fail(function (error) {
                    alert("County Error:" + error.StatusText);
             });
        });

        $('#Year').on("change", function () {
            var state = $('#State').val();
            var year = $('#Year').val();
            var obj = {
                state: state,
                year: year
            };

            alert("Year changed:" + state +":"+ year);

            AjaxCall('/RIC/GetCounties', JSON.stringify(obj), 'POST').done
                (function (response) {
                    if (response) {

                        $('#DataId').html("<option value='test'>Test</option>");
                        var options = '';
                        options += "<option value='Select'>Select</option>\n";
                        for (i in response) {
                            options += "<option value='" + response[i].DataId + "'>" + response[i].County + "</option>\n";
                        }
                        //$('#DataId').html("<option value='Select'>Select-Y</option><option value='16'>Alameda-Y</option>");
                        $('#DataId').html(options);                 //This should work.  How to get the value of options into the string
                        alert("Statitical Areas(Y): " + options);
                        //$('#DataId').append(options);

                    }
                }).fail(function (error) {
                    alert("County Error:" + error.StatusText);
                });
        });
    });

    function AjaxCall(url, data, type) {
          return  $.ajax({
                 url:  url,
                 type:  type  ?  type  :  'GET',
                 data:  data,
                 contentType:  'application/json'
           });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using another function to call your $.ajax why not call it immediately. There’s no performance improvement on what you had done. Try to revert your code and just add async property if you want to wait the response before proceeding to your lower conditions.

I hope this will help you

Comment: Dont forget to upvote :) or check as correct answer:)

Comment: For later use especially to other developers

Comment: Hi Kenneth, thanks for replay.
My question is between these two line:
$('#DataId').html(options);
vs.
$('#DataId').html("<option value='Select'>Select-S</option><option value='16'>Alameda-S</option>");

The 2nd line works, but not the first.
I can definite look into improvements one the issue is resolved.

Comment: Also instead of using done, try the ‘error’ and ‘success’ property of $.ajax. jquery.com for your reference

Comment: Cause u might want to consider separate handle when it is a success or an error response from the server.